# How to implement and use search textfield inside NSMenu?

Tags: swift, macos, menu, swiftui, uisearchbar

As shown in the screenshot below Google Chrome most likely has `NSMenu` in help and the first item in this `NSMenu` is the Search text field, which allows searching for different options.

If I want to implement the same using SwiftUI or Appkit+Swift, how would I go about it?

[image]

What I did so far?

`Appkit+Swift` approach:

I can use `NSMenu` to construct the menu item and add `NSTextField` for search purposes.
But I am lost after that and not able to find the good example of such approach further.

`SwiftUI` approach:

No idea here and any input is appreciated.

Comment: The search field you're seeing under the help commands is a default for all MacOS applications, you don't have to do anything.

Comment: Yes, but if I am trying to implement it in another custom menu how would I go about it ?